# Concatenate arrays from rows in a cell of varible size to single column vector in Matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, cell, concatenation

I am sorry for what could be a silly question. I have a cell array containing several row vectors (I do not know how many, this can vary) and I want to concatenate them in a single column array. For instance:

```
A = {[1 2 3]; [4 6 5 4 3 2 21 1]; [3 2 1 1 5 6 78 4]; [3 4]}
```

And I want to obtain B like:

```
B = [1;2;3;4;6;5;4;3;2;21;1;3;2;1;1;5;6;78;4;3;4]
```

I tried to do it in a for loop because I do not know how many arrays are contained in A, they are 4 in this example but their number can vary, so I wrote something like:

```
for i= 1:length(A)
    B= [vertcat(cell2mat(A(i)))'];
end
```

But this writes in a column only the results of the last array of A. How do I solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you transpose `A`, you can use `cell2mat` on the entire cell, which results in a row vector. Another transpose gives you the desired result.

```
B = cell2mat(A.').';
```

Comment: This worked perfectly. I am surprised that cell2mat permits me to concatenate arrays of different length

Comment: The magic here is transposing `A`. That way, `A` is a row and contains only row vectors. Then `cell2mat` can make 1 long row matrix out of it. Without transposing `A` first, `cell2mat` would throw an error.